# Why Disk utility shows different size than df -h?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, lvm

I have a hard time understanding what's going on with the space I have left in my laptop's SSD. The SSD's size is 256 GB, and my OS is Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS. When I installed Ubuntu, I used LVM and LUKS for encryption. It has only one Volume Group, and within it there are two Logical Volumes: 254 GB for the Filesystem Root including the home directory, and 1 GB for swap.

The problem I have is that in the disk utility, it says that there are **18 GB free** for root.
[image]

But if I right click on the home folder, and look in the Properties, it says I only have **4.8 GB free**. [image]

And if I right click in the root folder, and look in the properties it says that **231.6 GB are used, and 4.8 GB are free**, which doesn't add up to the 255 GB that I'm supposed to have in that Logical Volume; moreover, the pie chart shows a grey area that's not included in the used nor the free space, and is bigger than the free space.[image]

Also, the output of 'df -h' shows that the size of root is **only 233 GB**.
[image]

So, how much free space do I really have left?

Comment: Then when you format it, the ext4 is journalized so it reserves space for the journal. This improves performance and allows error correction for the cost of a small amount of space. Also reserves space for superuser. Also in Linux the default is to reserve 5% of the diskspace for the superuser, so you do not crash system when full. But either way you are full and need to do major houseclean or get larger drive.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the disk utility has a different method to calculate free space.
It appears you have approximately 4.5GB of free space.